# How could I redirect a root level domain to www subdomain with Zerigo DNS on Heroku?

Tags: networking, url, dns, heroku

I'm having trouble redirecting my root domain to a www subdomain ((e.g. blahblahblah.com to www.blahblahblah.com). I've a web app hosted on Heroku for which I've modified DNS settings through Zerigo DNS.

These are my current settings:

[image: Hosts settings on Zerigo DNS]

[image: Nameservers settings on Zerigo DNS]

However, this is the error I am getting when I type in, say, blahblahblah.com:
[image: Network Error]

Is there a problem with how things are currently set up, or is there anything else that I need to do in order for the redirect to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're getting a DNS error not a Heroku error so it could just be taking it's time to propagate