# Heroku SSL on root domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I am trying to setup SSL for my heroku app. I am using the hostname based SSL add-on. The heroku [documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#customdomain_ssl_wwwyourdomaincom) states the following:

```
Hostname based SSL will not work with root domains as it relies on CNAME 
aliasing of your custom domain names. CNAME aliasing of root domains is 
an RFC violation.
```

As expected everything works well when I access the site using the *www* subdomain, i.e. *https://www.foo.com*. The browser complains when I access *https://foo.com* as the certificate presented is for heroku.com.

I concluded that I have to redirect the traffic for *foo.com* to *www.foo.com* to address this issue. I am considering following approaches:

**1) DNS based redirection**

The DNS provider Zerigo [supports](https://www.zerigo.com/blog/2009/07/dns_updates_url_redirection_and_example_code_for_the_api) the *redirect* records. I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116052/how-could-i-redirect-a-root-level-domain-to-www-subdomain-with-zerigo-dns-on-hero) on a similar subject on SO.  I tried the solution, it works ONLY for HTTP redirection(Zerigo documentation confirms this).

*My Zerigo configuration:*

```
foo.com      A             x.x.x.x
foo.com      redirect      http://www.foo.com
www.foo.com  CNAME         zzz.amazonaws.com
```

**2) Rack based redirection**

Add a rack based middle-ware to perform the redirection. The [canonical-host](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host) gem provides such support.

```
use CanonicalHost do
  case Rails.env.to_sym
    when :staging     then 'staging.foo.com'
    when :production  then 'www.foo.com'
  end
end
```

I am wondering if there is a better solution for this(barring switching to $100 per month IP based SSL)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Wow...this took me forever, and a bunch of info on the web was wrong.  Even Heroku's docs didn't seem to indicate this was possible.

But Jesper J's answer provides a hint in the right direction: it works with DNSimple's ALIAS record which I guess is some new sort of DNS record they created.  I had to switch my DNS service over to them just to get this record type (was previously with EasyDNS).

To clarify when I say "works" I mean:

- entire site on SSL using your root domain
- no browser warnings
- using Heroku's Endpoint SSL offering ($20/month)

It works for *all* of the following urls (redirects them to https://foo.com with no warnings)

- http://foo.com
- http://www.foo.com
- https://www.foo.com
- https://foo.com

To summarize the important bits.

1. move your DNS over to DNSimple (if anyone knows other providers offering an ALIAS record please post them in the comments, they were the only one I could find)
2. setup Heroku endpoint ssl as normal https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint
3. Back in DNSimple add an `ALIAS` record pointing `foo.com` to your heroku ssl endpoint, something like `waterfall-9359.herokussl.com`
4. Also add a CNAME record pointing `www.foo.com` to your heroku ssl endpoint, `waterfall-9359.herokussl.com`
5. finally in your rails (or whatever) app make the following settings:

in `production.rb` set

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

in `application_controller.rb` add

```
before_filter :check_domain

def check_domain
  if Rails.env.production? and request.host.downcase != 'foo.com'
    redirect_to request.protocol + 'foo.com' + request.fullpath, :status => 301
  end
end
```

This finally seems to work!  The key piece seems to be the `ALIAS` dns record.  I'd be curious to learn more about how it works if anyone knows, and how reliable/mature it is.  Seems to do the trick though.

Comment: Heroku says [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate) that "You must enter a subdomain in the “Host Name” field." because a root-domain certificate is not compatible with Heroku's SSL endpoint.

Did you create a root-domain certificate or something like secure.foo.com? And does that affect the `request.host` check inside `check_domain`?

Comment: Can you please confirm if it is actually possible to use a root certificate.

Comment: I used a root certificate.  I emailed Heroku Support and they said this seemed to be what people are doing, and it seems to work with a Dnssimple ALIAS record.  But they don't want to endorse a particular dns provider so it's not in the official docs.  It would be nice if they added something in the docs or here.  There may be other performance implications I'm not aware of, so would be curious to hear more on it from their perspective.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you using a certificate for the root domain foo.com ? Or, are you using a wildcard certificate *.foo.com ? I'm using a certificate for my root domain but my browser keeps saying www.foo.com is not secured. When I close the warningthen it redirects as expected to foo.com and everything works fine there.

Comment: I'm wondering what the code in `application_controller` does. Does it redirect everything to `http://foo.com/`? (e.g. `https://www.foo.com/` becomes `https://foo.com/`, and `http://waterfall-9359.herokussl.com/` becomes `https://foo.com/`). If so, you'd need to change this code if you're using subdomains in your app, right?

Comment: Hmm, I still can't get this to work.  The Chrome error message continues to make an appearance.

Comment: I was using a wildcard certificate.

Comment: If anybody else is out there having trouble with this, I've found that the TTL MUST be >= 3600 for this configuration to work. At 60, Heroku appears to return the certificate for the wrong domain. I cannot explain this behavior, but that's what it took to get this configuration working for me.

Comment: For the 5th step I use https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite gem. In production.rb you can redirect http://foo.com and http://www.foo.com to https:www.foo.com. `config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{.*}, 'http://www.foo.com$&', :scheme => :http, :if => Proc.new {|rack_env| rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'foo.com' }
  r301 %r{.*}, 'https://www.foo.com$&',:scheme => :https,:if => Proc.new {|rack_env| rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'foo.com' }
end`

Comment: I bypassed the 5th step for `application_controller.rb` and everythings worked fine.

Comment: The blog post is not online anymore. For those who are looking for more information, you can take a look at:
http://jonathandean.com/2012/10/properly-handling-naked-domains-and-ssl-on-heroku/

And for more information about why we need to use ALIAS instead of CNAME:
http://blog.dnsimple.com/2014/01/why-alias-record/

Answer (score 8):

[DNSimple](http://dnsimple.com) offers an ALIAS record type to address this need. You can create an alias from your root domain (a.k.a zone apex) pointing to a CNAME. Read more about it here:

http://blog.dnsimple.com/introducing-the-alias-record/

Answer (score 1):

DNS redirects wouldn't care whether the inbound request is http or https so would maintain the original protocol - so would redirect http://foo.com to http://www.foo.com and the same for https.

You'll need to do it within the application via the gem you found or some other rack redirect gem or if www. is a problem use the IP based SSL addon.

Comment: As per Zerigo documentation DNS redirection works ONLY for http. https://www.zerigo.com/blog/2009/07/dns_updates_url_redirection_and_example_code_for_the_api. My final solution will be a mix of two styles.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you will like to keep in mind is that google might index both versions of your site if both versions are accessible (Root vs WWW). You would need to setup conicals to handle that which might be a pain to upkeep.

In my DNS settings I set up a URL / Forward record (DNS Simple)

```
URL foo.com     3600        http://www.foo.com
```

The CNAME setup only needs to be setup for WWW

```
CNAME   www.foo.com 3600        providedsslendpoint.herokussl.com
```

I also had to setup and Alias for my root

```
ALIAS   foo.com 3600        providedsslendpoint.herokussl.com
```

Then I decided to simply replace **foo.com** with an env variable `ENV['SITE_HOST']` (Where SITE_HOST= www.foo.com or whatever I might define). I can control this via my heroku configuration or my .env file (See https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). That way, I can control what happens in different environments.

For example, my test app uses **test.foo.com** as the url it also has its own SSL endpoint so that works fine for me. This also scales to create staging or qa specific environments as well.

```
  before_filter :check_domain

  def check_domain
    if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.testing? and request.host.downcase != ENV['SITE_HOST']
      redirect_to request.protocol + ENV['SITE_HOST'] + request.fullpath, :status => 301
    end
  end
```

From now on, end users will always access www with forced SSL. Old links will suffer a small hang but nothing noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

On the Rails part, to make the redirection, it'd be more sane to make it occur on the router layer, like this (works on Rails 3+):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  match '/*splat' => redirect { |_, request| request.url.sub('//www.', '//') }, :constraints => { :subdomain => 'www' }

  # ...

end
```

Answer (score 0):

For those heroku users using godaddy previously, I just finish porting the DNS over from godaddy to cloudflare. And the https is working fine now.

Godaddy DNS is incompatible with heroku. And this is due to:

> Some DNS providers will only offer A records for root domains.
>   Unfortunately, A records will not suffice for pointing your root
>   domains to Heroku because they require a static IP. These records have
>   serious availability implications when used in environments such as
>   on-premise data-centers, cloud infrastructure services, and platforms
>   like Heroku. Since Heroku uses dynamic IP addresses, it’s necessary to
>   use a CNAME-like record (often referred to as ALIAS or ANAME records)
>   so that you can point your root domain to another domain.

Setting up is fairly simple.

First, add the nameservers of the cloudflare into godaddy dns manager. These are some examples:

> roxy.ns.cloudflare.com 
>   sam.ns.cloudflare.com

Next, you only need two more steps.

1. Add a CNAME `NAME.com` and link it to `NAME.com.herokudns.com`
2. That's it. This is assuming that you already have a CNAME `www.NAME.com` linked to `www.NAME.com.herokudns.com`

If you are using Rails, be sure to set `config.force_ssl = true` at `config/environment/production.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I found DNSimple to be complicated for my current web developer competence. I finally signed up with easyDNS and moved the domain I purchased at Godaddy over to easyDNS. Annual cost for a standard easyDNS subscription is currently  $20. Good thing about easyDNS is that they actually answer their phone. A few minutes on the phone and I had my DNS target configured properly for Heroku. Tested my app and it worked for HTTP. When I upgraded my heroku app to a paid hobby dyno, which is currently $7/mo, it instantly applied SSL protection. Tested my app in the browser again, and it worked serving over HTTP and HTTPS. Next, I uncommented some code in my nodejs app that redirects http => https. One more test in a browser, seems good to go. Secure. Works with www and it works with the root domain. Bottom line: you may not have to pay for a Heroku Endpoint at $20/mo. Hope that helps.