# Adding an SSL Cert on heroku with godaddy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ssl-certificate

So here is the issue.

I have a site with SSL.  (https://www.archerandreed.com/)  It works great.

When you type archerandreed.com/ in the browser everything still works great.

Unfortunately when you type https://archerandreed.com/ or http://archerandreed.com/ into your browser you are given an SSL cert warning.

I thought I could just add a cert for www.archerandreed.com  && archerandreed.com but heroku no longer accepts 2 ssl endpoints.

So what are the possible solutions.  I assume one solution is to buy a wild card domain but that is painful.  My app is rails 3.2.6.  Is it possible to only force SSL if their is a subdomain?  Can I do that in routes.rb or in config/environments/production.rb?  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So I think I found what I was looking for and I think this should be documented somehow in heroku...

1) turn off config.force_ssl = true:

```
config.force_ssl = false  # config/environments/production.rb
```

2) in application_controller have the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :ensure_domain
  before_filter :force_ssl
  APP_DOMAIN = 'www.archerandreed.com'

protected
  def force_ssl
    if Rails.env.production?
      redirect_to :protocol => 'https' unless request.ssl?
    end
  end

  def ensure_domain
    if Rails.env.production? && ((request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != APP_DOMAIN) )
      # HTTP 301 is a "permanent" redirect
      redirect_to( "https://#{APP_DOMAIN}", :status => 301) and return
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you are right, I have spent today trying to sort this out. Heroku should have this on their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (as brought up in a couple other threads - e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701549/heroku-ssl-on-root-domain/11011004#11011004)) is to use a DNS provider like DNSimple that allows the use of ALIAS records. Then add an ALIAS record for your naked domain (in this case archerandreed.com), since you don't want to use A records for pointing your naked domain at heroku anyway.

You can then use `config.force_ssl` in production.rb and not have to add filters to your application controller.