# Are naked domains on heroku still unsafe when using DNSimple's ALIAS record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, hosting, dnsimple

We're hosting a Rails 3 app on Heroku. [Heroku suggests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords) redirecting naked domains (example.com) to sub-domains (www.example.com) when using their service. This is because they prefer CNAMES over A records (since their IP address might occasionally change).

However, personally I'd prefer to use a naked domain (instead of www) for our site. We're using [DNSimple](http://dnsimple.com) to manage the DNS for our site. If we use their [ALIAS feature](http://blog.dnsimple.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-alias-that-works/), does this mean that we should be able redirect all traffic to the naked domain without any worry?

Also, is there anything else we should be aware of when using a naked domain on Heroku, besides [following this advice in regards to SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701549/heroku-ssl-on-root-domain)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNSimple ALIAS record negates the problems usually experienced with naked domain so you will be fine.

Comment: I'm getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when users at domain.com query the api at www.domain.com and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set a wildcard domain to allow your app to control the routing if any subdomains... Here's what heroku says: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

I'm not sure of the security that way, but it might be a solution for you.