# SSL Heroku Dnsimple and security error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have followed a [previous posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701549/heroku-ssl-on-root-domain) on here on getting these three things working together, but I've become stumped.

I'm getting the following error when visiting www.myapp.com in most browsers. This is chrome's error-

```
You attempted to reach www.myapp.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as myapp.com.
```

Obviously, close but not quite what I want.  This is what I get when I run heroku domains-

```
myapp.com
secure.myapp.com
www.myapp.com
```

I have this method in my application controller (base on instruction from the SO answer I linked to)

```
  def check_domain
    if Rails.env.production? and request.host.downcase != 'myapp.com'
       redirect_to request.protocol + 'myapp.com' + request.fullpath, :status => 301
    end
  end
```

I'm using dnsimple and I have a CNAME record-

```
www.myapp.com pointing to running-water6577.herokussl.com
```

I have an ALIAS record-

```
myapp.com to running-water6577.herokussl.com
```

And a TXT record-

```
myapp.com to ALIAS for running-water6577.herokussl.com
```

I thought I had takin every measure to ensure all request for www.myapp.com or myapp.com would point to https://myapp.com but when typing www.myapp.com it resolves to https://www.myapp.com and it throws the above error in chrome and any other browser. I purchased through Rapidssl.

What have I misconfigured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming myapp.com is working correctly? It looks like your certificate is only valid for myapp.com (and not www.myapp.com) so instead of trying to serve SSL traffic via www.myapp.com you should configure DNSimple to do a redirect of www.myapp.com to myapp.com. That way users will only access your site through myapp.com and should get valid certificates.

Comment: Yes, myapp.com resolves with no security issues. Does that mean an ALIAS of myapp.com for www.myapp.com? Confused of the record configuration I would need to do with Dnsimple.

Comment: after seeing this from dnsimple http://support.dnsimple.com/questions/27485-Configuring-a-301-redirect I thought that the code on my application controller was supposed to do this for me, based off of the SO post I linked to in the first part of my question.

Comment: I wasn't clear, URL forward will only work for non-SSL requests: http://support.dnsimple.com/questions/22620-Can-a-URL-record-redirect-requests-over-SSL - basically, if you want to have anything reasonable happen when users access https://www.myapp.com/ you will need a certificate that's valid for that domain, either *.myapp.com or www.myapp.com

Comment: Ok this is where I get confused..Running `heroku certs` gives me `common names: myapp.com` I functionally want whenever a user enters www.myapp.com or myapp.com to resolve to a secure domain. Am I to understand I need to purchase a different type of SSL cert to achieve this?

Comment: Here's the problem: user enters www.myapp.com in address bar, DNS resolves that to some IP address, the browser sends ssl-request to that IP, the server (in your setup) presents a certificate that's valid only for myapp.com (which is NOT valid for www.myapp.com) and the browser goes "argh!" and shows the warning. To not get a warning when accessing www.myapp.com or any other subdomain, you have to a certificate for www.myapp.com or a wildcard *.myapp.com certificate.

Comment: Ok I understand this if the case is true that when buying an ssl cert there is no real point to buy a non wildcard cert if the browser will serve a warning if either www is used or it is not. That said is it bad practice to use an additional cert for the www. sub domain rather than purchasing a *.myapp as it would be cheaper to do the former?

Comment: Well, if you're not going to use www. or other subdomains, then just getting the apex cert is fine. The recommendation on Heroku currently is to run on the www. subdomain (because that works with a CNAME record instead of requiring an A record) so if that's what you're doing, consider just getting that.

Comment: According to the [DNSSimple support article](http://support.dnsimple.com/questions/48899-Selecting-the-Certificate-Hostname) you should purchase the cert for the www subdomain and this would work for the root domain as well.