# Getting ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error before redirecting to ssl page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have a Rails app on Heroku using Expedited SSL (in case any of that matters).

Now I have permanent forwarding from example.com to https://www.example.com. Occasionally, and I only noticed it on Chrome, when I request the page http://example.com, I get a ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error page, then after few seconds, it takes me to the https://www.example.com page and loads just fine.

I ran the inspector for http insecured warnings in console, but nothing. I tried several times to do curl, and on one occasion I got an error.

```
Bashar:example bashar$ curl -v http://example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://example.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* Connected to example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
Bashar:example bashar$ curl -v http://example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://example.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* Connected to example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Cache-Control: max-age=900
< Content-Type: text/html
< Location: https://www.example.com
* Server Microsoft-IIS/7.5 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 09:15:46 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Age: 1
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

I've read several discussions about the topic, but didn't find one exactly like this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is another, or better solution. However I found this answer by Brian [Heroku SSL on root domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701549/heroku-ssl-on-root-domain)
 to move from GoDaddy to DNSimple to do the trick. Can't see the problem anymore, and even better, the site works with and without www, and with http and https. Seems t